# How to get Indicator last value from a 5m chart

Tags: pine-script

Hi can I get indicator closing value only for the day to do calculation for next day? (Example : Standard deviation value as shown in the image)

Thank you

[Indicator Close value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joHJH.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
newDay = change(time("D")) != 0
sd = stdev(close, 20)
sdDailyClose = valuewhen(newDay, sd[1], 0)
```

This will give you the previous day's closing value.

If you want the value AT eod, you need to know the timeframe and your session's end time. This assumes 3:30pm closing (15:30)

```
var float closingSD = na
var int minutes = timeframe.isintraday ? 30 - timeframe.multiplier : na
sd = stdev(close, 20)
closingBarTime = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 15, minutes)
if time >= closingBarTime and barstate.isconfirmed
    closingSD := sd
```

If you are only going to use this on the 5m chart you can reduce it to this

```
var float closingSD = na
sd = stdev(close, 20)
closingBarTime = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 15, 25)
if time >= closingBarTime and barstate.isconfirmed
    closingSD := sd
```